# External HDD won't unmount

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I tried to unmount my external HDD from Finder, but the drive continued to make noise which means I can't plug it off. I checked the output of `diskutil list` and attempted to force unmount the disk, but it didn't work.

```
~ % diskutil list | grep /dev/disk5
/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
~ % diskutil list | grep disk5     
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk5⁩         700.0 GB   disk2s2
/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +700.0 GB   disk5
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨WD My Passport 2627 ...⁩ 786.4 KB   disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Time Machine⁩            132.7 GB   disk5s3
 % diskutil unmountDisk disk5
Unmount of all volumes on disk5 was successful
 % diskutil unmountDisk force disk5
Forced unmount of all volumes on disk5 was successful
 % diskutil list | grep disk5      
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk5⁩         700.0 GB   disk2s2
/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +700.0 GB   disk5
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨WD My Passport 2627 ...⁩ 786.4 KB   disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Time Machine⁩            132.7 GB   disk5s3
```

Comment: `disk5` is not the identifier for your external HDD. From what you have already posted, I assume the identifier for your external HDD is `disk2`. Have you tried `diskutil eject disk2`?